# PHP array from loop to string

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I import a CSV file with the following code (extract):

```
while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE){
//some mysql insert
$aff[] = $line[12];
}
```

Now I need to get some items to use them later in the code. I added the $aff variable, but was not able to create a string from the items.
The final string should be seperated with a comma: a, b, c
How can I do that? If I print the $aff out, it only says "Array".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use php's implode function -

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
$string = implode(",", $aff);
```

That will create a string separated by commas from your array.

Comment: you have forgotten a comma in your example $string = implode(",", $aff);

Comment: So I did - my keyboard does not like me today.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic PHP question. Googling something like concatenate array or something should give you the answer right away. The correct approach would be to use the function [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) with a separator:

```
echo implode(', ', $aff);
```

Also note that you should create the array outside of your loop if you don't already do this:

```
// Create empty array
$aff = [];

while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE){
//some mysql insert
$aff[] = $line[12];
}

// Output the array
echo implode(', ', $aff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use **concatenating assignment operato** and do **rtrim** and you got your solution

```
$str = "";
while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE){
//some mysql insert
$str  .= $line[12].", ";
}
echo echo rtrim($str,", ");
```